# Aggregate Function Error on an Expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What could be wrong with this query:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE 
          WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(StartDate,'01-01-1900') 
                FROM TestingTable  
                ORDER BY StartDate Asc) <> '01-01-1900' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Testingvalue.
```

The get the error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: The error message tells you EXACTLY what the problem is. Your logic as posted doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do here? As posted, this will give you a count of rows from the table if the earliest StartDate is greater than 1/1/1900, otherwise you get zero. If you can explain what you are trying to do we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As koppinjo stated what your current (broken) query is doing is checking if you have a `NULL`-value (or `StartDate = '01-01-1900'`) in your table, return either a `1` or a `0` depending on which, and then attempting to `SUM` that single value.

There are 2 different logical things you want.
Either getting the amount of rows that has a `StartDate` or checking if any row is missing `StartDate`.

```
SELECT --Checking if there is a NULL-value in table
(
  CASE WHEN 
    (SELECT TOP 1 ISNULL(StartDate,'01-01-1900')
    FROM TestingTable  
    ORDER BY StartDate Asc) <> '01-01-1900' THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
  END
) AS TestingValue 


SELECT SUM(TestingValue) TestingValue --Give the count of how many non-NULLs there is
FROM
(
SELECT 
CASE WHEN 
  ISNULL(StartDate,'01-01-1900') <> '01-01-1900' THEN 1 
  ELSE 0 
END AS TestingValue
FROM TestingTable  
) T
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e495e/1) showing both outputs side by side.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(TestingValue)
   FROM 
    (SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(StartDate,'01-01-1900') <> '01-01-1900' 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END AS TestingValue
     FROM  TestingTable) t
```

As your original query is written now, your subquery will return 1 value overall, so your sum would be 1 or 0 always, not to mention it is illegal.  To get around that, this SQL will apply the case statement to every row in the TestingTable and insert the result into a derived table (t), then the 'outer' select will sum the results.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think query got me closer to a solution. I want to get the the first data imputed into a given table. For example say I have a product that gets logged every time, I want to know the very first time the product was logged. This was the reason I included a "Select Top 1. How do I get around this?

Comment: It depends on what you are wanting to sum, which is where a real-world use case, business case, or sample data would be helpful.  If you only want to get one entry, then you don't need a sum and can do a select without the derived table.  If you want to get the first entry for a number of products or something (like there are multiple entries for the same ProductID and you want to get the first entry for each ProductId and sum THOSE results, then that is another situation).